# Java Counting swaps in Heap sort

Tags: java, counter, heapsort

I am trying to count the number of swaps that occurred in the heap sort and print it out, but I have having trouble figuring out where to put my counter. I have already been able to print out the random and heap arrays in sorted order, but every where I try to put a counter it says "unexpected return" so I'm at a loss now. Any help is appreciated. My code is below:

```
    import java.io.*;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Node
   {
   private int iData;             // data item (key)
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public Node(int key)           // constructor
      { iData = key; }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public int getKey()
      { return iData; }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   }  // end class Node
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Heap
   {
   private Node[] heapArray;
   private int maxSize;           // size of array
   private int currentSize;       // number of items in array
   public int heapSwap=0;
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public Heap(int mx)            // constructor
      {
      maxSize = mx;
      currentSize = 0;
      heapArray = new Node[maxSize];
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public Node remove()           // delete item with max key
      {                           // (assumes non-empty list)
      Node root = heapArray[0];
      heapArray[0] = heapArray[--currentSize];
      trickleDown(0);
      return root;
      }  // end remove()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void trickleDown(int index)
      {
      int largerChild;
      Node top = heapArray[index];        // save root
      while(index < currentSize/2)        // not on bottom row
         {
         int leftChild = 2*index+1;
         int rightChild = leftChild+1;
                                          // find larger child
         if(rightChild < currentSize &&   // right ch exists?
                             heapArray[leftChild].getKey() <
                             heapArray[rightChild].getKey())
            largerChild = rightChild;
         else
            largerChild = leftChild;
                                          // top >= largerChild?
         if(top.getKey() >= heapArray[largerChild].getKey())
            break;
                                          // shift child up
         heapArray[index] = heapArray[largerChild];
         index = largerChild;             // go down
         }  // end while
      heapArray[index] = top;             // root to index
      }  // end trickleDown()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void displayHeap()
      {
      int nBlanks = 32;
      int itemsPerRow = 1;
      int column = 0;
      int j = 0;                          // current item

      String dots = "...............................";
      System.out.println(dots+dots);      // dotted top line

      while(currentSize > 0)              // for each heap item
         {
         if(column == 0)                  // first item in row?
            for(int k=0; k<nBlanks; k++)  // preceding blanks
               System.out.print(' ');
                                          // display item
         System.out.print(heapArray[j].getKey());

         if(++j == currentSize)           // done?

            break;

         if(++column==itemsPerRow)        // end of row?
            {
            nBlanks /= 2;                 // half the blanks
            itemsPerRow *= 2;             // twice the items
            column = 0;                   // start over on
            System.out.println();         //    new row

            }


         else                             // next item on row
            for(int k=0; k<nBlanks*2-2; k++)
               System.out.print(' ');     // interim blanks
         }  // end for

      System.out.println("\n"+dots+dots); // dotted bottom line

      }  // end displayHeap()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void displayArray()
      {
      for(int j=0; j<maxSize; j++)
         System.out.print(heapArray[j].getKey() + " ");
      System.out.println("");
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void insertAt(int index, Node newNode)
      { heapArray[index] = newNode; }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void incrementSize()
      { currentSize++; }

// -------------------------------------------------------------
   }  // end class Heap
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class HeapSortApp
   {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      {
      int size, j;


      System.out.print("Enter number of items: ");
      size = getInt();
      Heap theHeap = new Heap(size);

      for(j=0; j<size; j++)       // fill array with
         {                        //    random nodes
         int random = (int)(java.lang.Math.random()*100);
         Node newNode = new Node(random);
         theHeap.insertAt(j, newNode);
         theHeap.incrementSize();
         theHeap.heapSwap++;
         }

      System.out.print("Random: ");
         theHeap.displayArray();  // display random array

      for(j=size/2-1; j>=0; j--)  // make random array into heap
         theHeap.trickleDown(j);

      System.out.print("Heap:   ");
      theHeap.displayArray();     // dislay heap array
      theHeap.displayHeap();      // display heap

      for(j=size-1; j>=0; j--)    // remove from heap and
         {                        //    store at array end
         Node biggestNode = theHeap.remove();
         theHeap.insertAt(j, biggestNode);

         }
      System.out.print("Number of swaps: " + theHeap.heapSwap);
      System.out.print("\n\nSorted: ");
      theHeap.displayArray();     // display sorted array
      }  // end main()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public static String getString() throws IOException
      {
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String s = br.readLine();
      return s;
      }
//-------------------------------------------------------------
   public static int getInt() throws IOException
      {
      String s = getString();
      return Integer.parseInt(s);
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
  }  // end class HeapSortApp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Can you show us what your code looks like when you try to add the counter, and what the exact error message you get is? Please edit the question to include this information.

Comment: Additionally, when showing the error, **do not forget that we cannot see line numbers in stack overflow.** I recommend you use a primitive array e.g. `int [] arr = new int[maxSize];` and the counter, given that you have methods, could be an instance variable.

Comment: Changes added in the question. I added this in main()..      for(j=size-1; j>=0; j--)    // remove from heap and
         {                        //    store at array end
         Node biggestNode = theHeap.remove();
         theHeap.insertAt(j, biggestNode);
         swaps ++;
         }
      System.out.print("Number of swaps: " + swaps);

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable inside the class but outside the sort method so it doesn't get wiped out when the method returns.

```
class Heap {
  public int swapCount=0;
  [...]
}
```

```
class HeapSortApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    [...]
    Heap heap = new Heap(size);
    [...]
    heap.swapCount++;
    [...]
  }
}
```

If you want to be able to access this variable from another class, such as `HeapSortApp`, the variable must be public.

Comment: It is still telling me that the swaps are 1000 when that's the number of items I entered. I added my edits in the question. Its just not counting the swaps and I'm not sure why it is taking the number of items entered as the number of swaps as well.

Comment: Maybe that is the actual number of swaps.

Comment: Here is an example of what my output is... run:
Enter number of items: 10
Random: 82 67 83 96 84 5 28 28 20 84 
Heap:   96 84 83 67 84 5 28 28 20 82 
..............................................................
                                96
                84                              83
        67              84              5              28
    28      20      82
..............................................................
Number of swaps: 10

Sorted: 5 20 28 28 67 82 83 84 84 96 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: You are doing this: ```for(j=0; j<size; j++) { [...]theHeap.heapSwap++; }``` so of course that will run ```size``` times.

Comment: You are bumping your counter when you insert nodes, not when you swap. You need to identify where the actual swap is taking place and bump the counter there.

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you